# Nodejs $lookup not getting expected output

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to join two documents where in first collection prefix has categoryId which is array of id's and the second collection is categories  that has _id(objectId)
& this is my sample DB's

```
  "prefix": [
    {
      "_id": "648c39f13af539b8dfebdf9d",
      "categoryId": [
        "648468306806396cd3ab9710",
        "648850199e779dfd371a2766"
      ],
      "name": "Test Name",
      
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "_id": "648468306806396cd3ab9710",
      "name": "Cat A",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": "648850199e779dfd371a2766",
      "name": "Cat B",
      
    },
    
  ]
}
```

this is my aggregate query which works on Mongo Playground but its not working in my node setup

```
db.prefix.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "cat_ids": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$categoryId",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            "$toObjectId": "$$item"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "localField": "categoryId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "categoryDetail"
    }
  }
])
```

I am getting this output on playground(https://mongoplayground.net/p/0oFbyXDwpct) but its not working in my nodejs code

```
  {
    "_id": "648c39f13af539b8dfebdf9d",
    "cat_ids": [
      ObjectId("648468306806396cd3ab9710"),
      ObjectId("648850199e779dfd371a2766")
    ],
    "categoryDetail": [
      {
        "_id": "648468306806396cd3ab9710",
        "name": "Cat A"
      },
      {
        "_id": "648850199e779dfd371a2766",
        "name": "Cat B"
      }
    ],
    "categoryId": [
      "648468306806396cd3ab9710",
      "648850199e779dfd371a2766"
    ],
    "name": "Test Name"
  }
]
```

**Node version 18, mongodb version 5.0.4**

Comment: What output are you getting when you run your node app?

Comment: Here i think you don't want to use the "SET stage" because  "$lookup" also applicable on array of Object ids  ,  so "without SET stage" you get your desired output in the "categoryDetail"  after that you can "unwind stage" it if you need

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, does this pipeline work for you?

```
db.prefix.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "cat_ids": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$categoryId",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            "$toObjectId": "$$item"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "localField": "cat_ids",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "categoryDetail"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bhou73GRmTm).

The difference between it and the one you provided are:

1. The data type for the `_id` field was changed from string to ObjectId. That is the default type for that field.
2. The `localField` of the `$lookup` was changed to use the `cat_ids` field that the pipeline was already generating. That field represents the existing array of `categoryId` strings but cast to ObjectIds.

Your original playground had the `_id` fields of the data set to strings which is why using the array of strings already present in the `categoryIds` field returned results. My guess is that the `_id` fields instead have the default ObjectId type and, moreover, that's why you were generating the converted values in `cat_ids` in the first place.

Personally I'd also suggest storing the array as ObjectIds to begin with as well, but obviously you don't have to.